# string operations, for loop doesnt work

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written this to get the index of first character of string s1 which has come in string s2, but doesn't give the correct answer and every time it throws different wrong answers, anyone knows why?

```
s1 = input ('enter the s1 string: ')
s2 = input ('enter the s2 string: ')
for i in range (0, len(s1)):
    if s1[i] in s2:
        n= (s1.index(s1[i]))
    else:
        n= -1
print (n)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should stop iteration when match found:

```
s1 = input('enter the s1 string: ')
s2 = input('enter the s2 string: ')
n = -1
for i in range(0, len(s1)):
    if s1[i] in s2:
        n = i # Stop iteration when match character found.
        break
print(n)
```

Just reference `i` instead of `s1.index(s1[i])`.